# Call Adminhtml controller action from frontend

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm trying to write a module which allows users create their own shop in our system (multi-store function).

I'm wondering, is it possible to execute an adminhtml controller's functions in Magento frontend?

At this moment, I've just create folder and edit `index.php, .htaccess` when click save website in Magento backend. I need more than that, please help.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to call an adminhtml controller from the frontend, no.

You need to specify the router between `<frontend/>` nodes of your module's `config.xml` file.

[Magento for Developers: Part 3 - Magento Controller Dispatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch)

Comment: Thank you, but how people can add category/product from frontend? (Like multi-vendor extension). I think there is some way to add new store from frontend, isn't it?